# Listing all referenced assemblies

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compact-framework

How to list all referenced assemblies? (referenced assemblies from referenced assemblies...) and there targeting framework (.NetCF2.0, .Net 2.0)?
Are there any apps (or Reflector plugins) ?

My problem is that when I deploy a CF application in VS2005 some Assemblies from the full .Net framework are deployed. But I don't know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

http://checkasm.booring.net/

?

Comment: Thanks, I've found my "bad" assembly =)

Answer (score 1):

NDepend ?
http://www.ndepend.com/